# Netty Not Scaling for Higher concurrency

Tags: multithreading, performance, concurrency, netty, nio

We are working on a Netty based HTTP server which receives a Get Request, decodes the request parameters, makes a couple of webservice  calls and then returns the result after some processing

A typical request generally completes in around 320ms out of which apprixmately 300ms are spent waiting for a response from the remote servers.

The problem is that we are not able to generate high throughput on the setup.

This is a 16 core machine with 30 GB RAM. The cpu usage never goes beyond 20% and RAM udage never goes beyond 5GB. The java heap size is set to 25GB

Additionally we have updated the following OS settings

```
ulimit =65000
net.core.somaxconn = 2048
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10240    65535
```

This is an ubuntu machine and we are using the 3.2 branch of Netty

The max throughput that we can achive on the server is around 300 requests per second which also goes down with each subsequent test which finally goes down to 35 req/s.

We have tried using the FixThreadPool as well as the cachedthreadpool while creating the netty server bootstrap.

Whatever we do the performance numbers do not change

Our guess is that Netty is not creating enough threads and hence a lot of time is wasted in the queue.

Is there something basic that we are missing due to which netty is giving us fixed concurrency?

How do we make maximum use of our CPU/RAM to get maximum performance from our hardware?

here is the code used for netty initialization

```
   ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap(
                new NioServerSocketChannelFactory(
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool(),
                        Executors.newCachedThreadPool()));
                        //Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5000),5000));
   // Configure the pipeline factory.


     bootstrap.setPipelineFactory(this.nettyServerPipeline);
       bootstrap.setOption("child.tcpNoDelay", true);
       bootstrap.setOption("backlog",1000);
       bootstrap.setOption("keepAlive", true);
       bootstrap.setOption("connectTimeoutMillis", 10000);
       bootstrap.setOption("client.reuseAddress", true);
       // Bind and start to accept incoming connections.
       bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(8099));
    /*  ServerBootstrap bootstrap =
        new ServerBootstrap(new         NioServerSocketChannelFactory(Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1),
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(32)));
    */
```

We have tried multiple combinations of above settings but nothing seems to improve the absolute throughput.

Regards
Sanket

Comment: Are you actually waiting for the WS response ? If so, switch to asynchronous dispatch and response handling.

Comment: The webservice call is made using a Netty client. The processing thread is free while the webservice call is being made

Comment: Did you check with a profiler if you may block the worker threads ?

Comment: What level of performance can you expect from the remote servers? Can the remote servers throttle you?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting a limit on the number of TCP connections that can be open. This can be limited by a number of factors.

If you have iptables (firewall) running you may be hitting the number of connections that are tracked - https://serverfault.com/questions/10852/what-limits-the-maximum-number-of-connections-on-a-linux-server

You might also try `fs.file-max` in addition to the ulimit.

The `net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse` setting may also be impacted by how long TCP connections are allowed to be in `TIME_WAIT`. Try changing the follow:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl = 15
net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes = 5
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout = 5
```

Finally, there's a limit on the number of TCP connections that can be created for each source + destination pair. So, if your test load is coming from a small number of servers, you may be artificially limiting your server.

Comment: Hi fs.file-max is already set to a high value of 3061566. No firewall is running on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Based on suggestions received on this thread,we noticed that we were making some calls to memcached which seemed to be blocking the worker Threads

We managed to fix the issue by creating a new Execution handler and passing it to the nettypipeline

Original Code

```
 ChannelPipeline pipeline =
        new StaticChannelPipeline( new HttpRequestDecoder(), new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576),
            requestDecoder, new HttpResponseEncoder(),
           nettyServerHandler,filterHandler);

    return pipeline;
```

New Code

```
 ChannelPipeline pipeline = new StaticChannelPipeline( new HttpRequestDecoder(), 
   new HttpChunkAggregator(1048576),requestDecoder, 
   new HttpResponseEncoder(),nettyServerHandler,
   executionHandler ,filterHandler);

        return pipeline;

 private final ExecutionHandler executionHandler = new ExecutionHandler(
       //new MemoryAwareThreadPoolExecutor(6400,65536, 1048576,10,TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

This seems to fix the concurrency issue but we are currently looking to fix some memory leaks that have sprung up.